# Storing multiple values from the same object in an Array

Tags: java

I am trying to create an Array with all these values form the Detail Class. Is there a better way of creating this array?

```
Details[] DetailsArray = new Details[10];
        Details Details = new Details();
        Details Details2 = new Details();
        Details Details3 = new Details();
        Details Details4 = new Details();
        Details Details5 = new Details();
        Details Details6 = new Details();


        Details.setNumber(new Integer(1));
        Details2.setEmployeeID(new Double(300));
        Details3.setCurrency("Euro");
        Details4.setSize(new Double (400));
        Details5.setEvent("Something");
        Details6.setId(new Integer(10));


        DetailsArray[0] = Details;
        DetailsArray[1] = Details2;
        DetailsArray[2] = Details3;
        DetailsArray[3] = Details4;
        DetailsArray[4] = Details5;
        DetailsArray[5] = Details6;

        System.out.println(DetailsArray);
        EmployeeDetails.setDetails(DetailsArray);
```

Comment: IMHO, if a `Details` object is capable of storing any one of those attributes, but is reserving space for all of them, you're doing it wrong.  Especially if you're using six of them!

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop?

```
Details[] detailsArray = new Details[10];
for (int i = 0; i < detailsArray.length; i++)
    detailsArray[i] = new Details();

detailsArray[0].setNumber(New Integer(1));
...
```

That being said ... rarely in real code would you have a static array that you're populating like this manually. If you did, you might want to have the data for those objects in an external file, or really some other data structure completely.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's pretty odd code to start with to be honest, but this would work:

```
// Why are you creating an array with 10 elements but only using 6?
Details[] detailsArray = new Details[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    detailsArray[i] = new Details();
}

detailsArray[0].setNumber(new Integer(1));
detailsArray[1].setEmployeeID(new Double(300));
detailsArray[2].setCurrency("Euro");
detailsArray[3].setSize(new Double (400));
detailsArray[4].setEvent("Something");
detailsArray[5].setId(new Integer(10));
```

Do you *really* want to set a different property on each object? Are you sure you don't *really* want to set multiple properties on a single object?

Comment: it's very odd code - I'd love to see HTH the `Details` class is supposed to work!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list instead of an array, but if I understand what you are trying to achieve, you maybe want this instead, where your `details` object holds all the information for that employee:

```
    Details details = new Details();

    details.setNumber(new Integer(1));
    details.setEmployeeID(new Double(300));
    details.setCurrency("Euro");
    details.setSize(new Double (400));
    details.setEvent("Something");
    details.setId(new Integer(10));

    System.out.println(details);
    EmployeeDetails.setDetails(details);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create constructor that accepts all needed parameters. Then do something like this:

deatilsArray = new DetailsArray[] {
    new Details(1, 300, "Euro", 400, "Something"),
    new Details(2, 400, "Dollar", 500, "Something else"),
    ..................
};

Alternatively you can create other class DetailsBuilder that initiates details' fields:

```
Details d = 
new DetailsBuilder().create().setName("aaa").setEmployeeId(123).setCurrency("Euro").getInstance();
```

In this case the code above will look like:

```
DetailsBuilder builder = new DetailsBuilder();
deatilsArray = new DetailsArray[] {
builder.create().setName("aaa").setEmployeeId(123).setCurrency("Euro").getInstance(),
builder.create().setName("bbb").setEmployeeId(123).setCurrency("Euro").getInstance(),
};
```

BTW according to java naming convention variable names always start with small letter.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a temporary inner class.

```
    class Pwn {
          final Details d = new Details();
    }

    Details[] detailsArray = new Details[] {
        (new Pwn (){{ d.setNumber(new Integer(1));      }}).d,
        (new Pwn (){{ d.setEmployeeID(new Double(300)); }}).d,
        (new Pwn (){{ d.setCurrency("Euro");            }}).d,
        (new Pwn (){{ d.setSize(new Double (400));      }}).d,
        (new Pwn (){{ d.setEvent("Something");          }}).d,
        (new Pwn (){{ d.setId(new Integer(10));         }}).d
    }
```

:)

Comment: Pwned! :) Poor man's closures sometimes do really work. For example in unit tests.